# a possible bug in IntervalUnion when applied to DateInterval

Tags: bugs, date-and-time, intervals

**Bug introduced in 13.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.2.0 or later.**

---

It seems `IntervalUnion` may lead to unexpected results when applied to `DateInterval` with a granularity other than `"Instant"`.

For instance, for

```
dtInt = DateInterval[{{2020, 5, 3}, {2021, 9, 6}}]
```

[image],

```
IntervalUnion[dtInt]=== dtInt
```

is supposed to give `True` but instead gives `False` as `IntervalUnion[dtInt]` evaluates into

[image].

Note the one day difference for the ending timestamps between `dtInt` and `IntervalUnion[dtInt]`.

I'm wondering if this should be considered as a bug or something I'm missing?

Comment: "IntervalUnion" takes "Interval" as arguments, not "DateInterval"

Comment: @DanielHuber No; please see this: https://wolfram.com/xid/0i1o1d4ti-dwtidm

Comment: this bug persists in 13.0.1.

Answer (score 3):

After looking into the implementation of `DateInterval`, it seems this is indeed a bug in the internal conversion between numerical representation of a DateObject and its standard form.

When converting the ending timestamp of a numerical interval to a DateObject, the granularity should be deducted for a correct offset:

```
ResourceFunction[
  "PrintDefinitions"][DateAndTime`NumericValueListToDateInterval]
```

[image]

While it seems granularity is correctly accounted for in the following conversion:

```
ResourceFunction[
  "PrintDefinitions"][DateAndTime`DateIntervalToNumericValueList]
```

[image]

then click into `dateToNumericValue`:

[image]

A bug report has been filed to WRI [CASE:4897342].